# How to skip missing items in a loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
dictionary = {'Mon':['Mary','Suszie','Larry'],
              'Tue':['Sam','Ola','Chris'],
              'Wed':['Tanner','Ram','Dustin']}
```

I am using this dictionary to generate plots from a larger datasets. If I call the key 'Mon' and let's say the value 'Larry' isn't present in my dataset, my loop fails at 'Larry' with an error. How can I make my loop skip missing items?

Code example:

```
dataset = {'Mary':[1,4,6,2,7],
           'Suszie':[9,2,6,4,7],
           'Max':[1,3,1,3,5]}

for x in dictionary.values():
    for z in datasets.keys():
        if x not in z:
           continue
             plt.plot(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it:

```
for x in dictionary.values():
    for v in x:
        if v not in dataset:
           continue
        plt.plot(dataset[v])
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataset.keys()` is a set-like object, including support for things like `&`:

```
for names in dictionary.values():
    for z in dataset.keys() & names:
        plt.plot(dataset[z])
```

The `dict_keys` object must be on the left; the right-hand operand of `dict_keys.__and__` can be any iterable value.

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary` is a structure that is hard to work with: it is a dictionary where the values are list of names. It would be simpler to convert this `dictionary` into a simple set of names.

```py
import itertools
all_persons = set(itertools.chain(*dictionary.values()))
# all_persons is
# {'Mary', 'Larry', 'Ola', 'Tanner', 'Suszie', 'Dustin', 'Ram', 'Sam', 'Chris'}

for person in dataset.keys() & all_persons:
    plt.plot(dataset[person])
```

In the code above, I converted `dictionary` from a dictionary to `all_person`, which is a set of person names. From there, the loop would be simple and we don't need any `if` statement at all.